# Push vs Pull for GCP Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

I want to know what type of subscription one should create in GCP pubsub in order to handle high-frequency data from pubsub topic.
I will be ingesting data in dataflow with 100 plus messages per second.
Will pull or push subscription really matters and how it will gonna affect the speed and all.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow =) Please check how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Spending a few extra minutes making your question clear and specific will greatly improve the changes someone answers it AND that the answer is helpful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you consume the PubSub subscription with Dataflow, only Pull subscription is available

- either you create one and you give it in the parameter of your dataflow pipeline
- or you specify only the topic in your dataflow pipeline and Dataflow will create by itself the pull subscription.

If both case, Dataflow will process the messages in streaming mode

**The difference**

If you create the subscription by yourselves, all the messages will be stored and kept (up to 7 days by default) and will be consumed when the dataflow pipeline will be started.

If you let Dataflow to create the subscription, only the message that arrives AFTER the subscription creation will be consumed by the dataflow pipeline. If you want to not loose a message, it's not the recommended solution. If you don't care about the old message, it's a good choice.

**High frequency**

Then, 100 messages per second is absolutely not high frequency. 1 pubsub topic can ingest up to 1 000 000 of messages per second. Don't worry about that!

**Push VS Pull**

The model is different.

- With the push subscription, you have to specify an HTTP endpoint (on GCP or elsewhere) that consumes the message. It's a webhook pattern. If the platform endpoint scale automatically with the traffic (Cloud Run, Cloud Functions for example), the message rate can go very high!! And the HTTP return code stands for message acknowledgment.
- With Pull subscription, the client needs to open a connection to the subscription and then pull the message. The client needs to explicitly acknowledge the messages. Several clients can be connected at the same time. With the client library, the message is consumed with gRPC protocol and it's more efficient (in terms of network bandwidth) to receive and consume the message

*Security point of view*

With push, it's the PubSub to be authenticated on the HTTP endpoint, if the endpoint required authentication

With pull, it's the client that needs to be authenticated on the PubSub subscription.